# How to track Fast Moving Objects?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning

I'm trying to create an application that will be able to track rapidly moving objects in video/camera feed, however have not found any CV/DL solution that is good enough. Can you recommend any computer vision solution for tracking fast moving objects on regular laptop computer and web cam? A demo app would be ideal.

For example see this video where the tracking is done in hardware (I'm looking for software solution) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn5YQVvW-hQ

Answer (score 5):

Target tracking is a very difficult problem. In target tracking you will have **two main issues**: the motion uncertainty problem, and the origin uncertainty problem. The first one refers to the way you model object motion so you can predict its future state, and the second refers to the issue of data association(what measurement corresponds to what track, and the literature is filled with [scientific](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/4/1110) ways in which this issue can be approached).

Before you can come up with a solution to your problem you will have to answer some questions yourself, regarding the tracking problem you want to solve. For example: what are the values that you what to track(this will define your state vector), how are those values related to one another, are you trying to perform single object tracking or multiple object tracking, how are the objects moving( do they have a relatively constant acceleration or velocity ) or not, do objects make turns, can objects also be occluded or not and so on.

The **Kalman Filter** is good solution to predict the next state of your system (once you have identified your process model). A deep learning alternative to the Kalman filter is the so called [Deep Kalman Filter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05121) which essentially is used to do the same thing. In case your process or measurement models are not linear, you will have to linearize them before predicting the next state. Some solutions that deal with non-linear process or measurement models are the **Extended Kalman Filter** (EKF) or **[Unscented Kalman Filter](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unscented-kalman-filter-anything-ekf-can-do-i-can-do-it-better-ce7c773cf88d)** (UKF).

Now related to fast moving objects, an idea you can use is to have a larger covariance matrix since the objects can move a lot more if they are fast, so the search space for the correct association has to be a bit larger. Additionally you can use multiple motion models in case your motion model cannot be satisfied with only one model. 
In case of occlusions I will leave you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764238/image-processing-what-are-occlusions/60644446#60644446) stack overflow thread, where I have given an answer covering more details regarding occlusion handling in case of tracking. I have added some references for you to read. You will have to provide more details in your question, if you would like to receive more information regarding a solution (for example you should define fast moving objects with respect to camera frame rate).

I personally do not think there is a silver bullet solution for the tracking problem, I prefer to tailor a solution to the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of tracking fast-moving objects (FMO) is a known research topic in computer vision. FMOs are defined as objects which move over a distance larger than their size in one video frame. The solutions which have been proposed use classical image processing and energy minimization to establish their trajectories and sharp appearance.

If you need a demo app, I would suggest this GitHub repository: https://github.com/rozumden/fmo-cpp-demo. The demo is written in OpenCV/C++ and runs in real-time. The authors also provide a mobile app version, which is still in testing mode. Using this demo app you can track any fast moving objects in real-time without even providing an object model. However, if you provide object size in real-world units, the app can also estimate object speed.

A more sophisticated algorithm is open-sourced here: https://github.com/rozumden/deblatting_python, written in Python and PyTorch for speed-up. The repository contains a solution to the deblatting (deblurring and matting) problem, exactly what happens when a Fast Moving Object appears in front of a camera.

Answer (score 1):

The tracking problem is complicated. It is also more in the realm of control systems than computer vision. It would be also helpful to know more about your situation, as the performance of the chosen method pretty much depends on your problem constraints. Are you interested in real-time tracking? Are you trying to reconstruct an existing trajectory? Are there multiple targets? Just one? Are the physical properties of the targets (i.e. velocity, direction, acceleration) constant?

One of the most basic tracking methods is implemented by a **Linear Dynamic System** (LDS) description, in concrete, a discrete implementation, since we’re working with discrete frames of information. This method is purely based on physics, and its prediction is very sensitive. Depending on your application, the error rate could be acceptable… or not.

A more robust solution is **Kalman’s Filter**, and it is pretty much the go-to answer when tracking is needed. It implements prediction based on all the measurements obtained so far during the model's lifetime. It mainly works on constant-based measurements (velocity and acceleration) although it can be extended to handle non-constant models. If you are working with targets that won't exhibit a drastic change in their velocity, this is what you (probably) should implement.

I'm sorry I can't provide you with more, but the topic is pretty extensive and, admittedly, the details are beyond my area of expertise. Hopefully, this info should give you a little bit of context for finding a solution.